# Powershell does not create a folder when I run a script. What's wrong?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to have powershell create a folder for me and it works fine when I type it into the console. However, when I run the same command as a script, no folder is created and no error messages are supplied.

This is the line of code I am using.

```
new-item - path c:\test\ -name testfolder -itemtype directory
```

edit: I am on Windows 7

Comment: sounds like a permissions problem.  what user is it running as a script?

Comment: Is the space in `- path` part of the command in the script but not in the command you are typing manually?

Comment: @EtanReisner oops, that was a mistake on here. The actual script does not have the space.

Comment: @bowlturner I'm trying to run the script myself from the same account I tried the console on.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the error message that is returned by the script?

Comment: And make sure the code here is **exactly** the same as you have it in the script. Don't edit for posting if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a comment, but I cannot comment. There is definitely nothing wrong with that line of code. It runs on my machine, either from the terminal window or as a script. Because the code works for you at the terminal window but not when executing as a script my first guess is that your system may be configured to disallow powershell scripts. This is the default setting, and it will prevent a script file from executing but will not prevent commands typed at the prompt from working. Open a powershell session and type get-executionpolicy. If it returns "restricted" then you have found the culprit. This setting can be changed by opening an elevated powershell session (run as admin) and typing set-executionpolicy -executionpolicy RemoteSigned. Of course you should read about what those settings mean before changing them to determine what is best for your situation. For example the remotesigned option means that scripts originating from your machine will execute without a trusted signature, but external scripts will require a signature.